# Is it possible to use RedisRepositories and KeyValueRepositories?

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis, spring-data-keyvalue

I'm trying to use `@EnableRedisRepositories` and `@EnableMapRepositories` in a project and I'm getting the following error message:

> Related cause:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'redisConverter': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument
>   value of type
>   [org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.mapping.context.KeyValueMappingContext]
>   to required type
>   [org.springframework.data.redis.core.mapping.RedisMappingContext]:
>   Failed to convert value of type
>   'org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.mapping.context.KeyValueMappingContext'
>   to required type
>   'org.springframework.data.redis.core.mapping.RedisMappingContext';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type
>   'org.springframework.data.keyvalue.core.mapping.context.KeyValueMappingContext'
>   to required type
>   'org.springframework.data.redis.core.mapping.RedisMappingContext': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

So is it possible to use both in the same project?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 3):

There is known issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-846.

As a workaround you may disable repository auto configuration:

```
spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false
```

And add

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages="org.my.redis.repositories")
```

instead.

Comment: You also need to ensure `@EnableRedisRepositories` gets processed before `@EnableMapRepositories` meaning; if they are on same class `@EnableRedisRepositories` needs to appear on top of `@EnableMapRepositories`.